# How to release current thread when invoking a blocking call and continue when the call returns in asynchronous coding in java

Tags: java, multithreading, blocking

I want to release current thread when invoking a blocking call and continue when the call returns in asynchronous coding in java. The example is as follows:

```
public class Thread1 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        someBlockingCall();  // when do this calling, I want the current thread can be relased to do some other stuff, like execute some other Runnable object
        getResult();  // when return from the blocking call, something can inform the thread to continue executing, and we can get the result
    }
}
```

How can I realize this? Please help me.

Comment: Maybe you want to look into `CompletableFuture`s for this. And not exactly threads, but an abstraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conclusion, currently there is no way to realize my thought as I wrote in this question, because you can not just make two parallele statements execute in two different threads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly call `someBlockingCall()` asynchronously, then block to wait for the result when it's due

```
public void run() {
    CompletableFuture<ResultType> result = 
             CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> someBlockingCall());

    //do some other work here while someBlockingCall() is running async
    //this other work will be done by the first (main?) thread

    ResultType finalResult = result.join(); //get (or wait for) async result

    //Now use the result in the next call
    getResult();
}
```

If `someBlockingCall()` has a void return type, you can use `CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> someBlockingCall());`, with the future being of type `CompletableFuture<Void>`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I don't want to wait for the async result. And I don't wirte extra code between CompletableFuture.supplyAsync and result.join(). I just want to release the current thread so it can be scheduled to do something else. And I want to be waken up when the call returns. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @celia. If all you want is to start the async work, then you can just call supplyAsync or runAsync and return from the method. If you want to do something after the async job is done, then you can chain `result` with something, like `result.thenAccept()` or `thenApply` etc., which will be a call back run after async execution. Are you saying you want the call back to run in the exact same thread that kicked off the async work? Why do you need that? AFAIK, either you just execute a given call back, or you block on that initial thread to run the work in it.

Comment: we don't want other people who deal with the result to know this is async code. So they won't put their code in between calling blocking method and dealing with the result. But I need to return the result to them. By the way, I don't need to run the async work in the exact same thread that runs the async work.